# Killing every root process over a certain pid

Tags: grep, kill

I want to kill every process that is root and not mine.
Now there's:

```
sudo pkill -u root
```

But... Well, it kind of, I don't know, MAKES THE WHOLE COMPUTER TO CRASH.
So, I need a way to kill every root process with a pid bigger than 3000 (and compare it with mine so I won't end up killing myself).
I get I probably need to use something like:

```
sudo pkill -u root $(pgrep ...)
```

But how do I actually do that, WHILE comparing with mine.
Maybe I can do it in a program ?
Any idea?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you'd asked how to do that in Bash the stackoverflow guys probably should've helped. Or at least sent it to Unix & Linux, why is it here on AskUbuntu, it's for Ubuntu only?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 0):

This should do something like you want. I used a similar one the other day.

```
for p in `ps -ef | grep ^root | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2}' | sort -n`; do if ($p -gt 3000); then kill -9 $p;fi; done
```